# Redux-saga: How to stop or cancel task chain?

Tags: redux-saga

Have async increment saga, which increment counter after 3 seconds

```
function* incrementAsync() {
    yield call(delay, 3000);
    yield put(counterIncrement());
}

function* incrementAsyncWatcher() {
    yield takeEvery(ASYNC_INCREMENT, incrementAsync);
}

function* incrementCounterSaga() {
    yield fork(incrementAsyncWatcher);
}

const task = sagaMiddleware.run(incrementCounterSaga);
```

then I try to stop this saga

```
task.cancel();

store.dispathch({ type: ASYNC_INCREMENT });
```

but after 3 seconds see that saga is still working!

How to stop this saga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that explicit task cancellation can be really challenging since you have to pass and manage the task object.

Instead, I thought that patterns like this worked:

```
function* incrementAsyncWatcher() {
    yield takeLatest(ASYNC_INCREMENT, incrementAsync);
}
```

`takeLatest` will cancel the task, whereas `takeEvery` creates a new task.

You can also lookup the [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RacingEffects.html) for `race` to get cancellation implicitly